# frogs puzzle using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, puzzle

The problem is to write a program that solves the frogs and toads puzzle and with this specific program it has to function with recursion ,so it must have no for/while loops. The puzzle is basically the frogs on the left and the toads are on the right and these two groups are separated by an empty space and the winning state is all the toads are on the left and the frogs are on the right and the empty space is between the two again. The expected result of he program is after the user enters the number of frogs and toads they want then the program will reveal the initial state of the puzzle then through recursion it will print the solved puzzle but from the solved state to the initial state, i.e:

````
    |Toad|Toad|Frog| |
    |Toad| |Frog|Toad|
    |Toad|Frog| |Toad|
    | |Frog|Toad|Toad|
    |Frog| |Toad|Toad|


def make_state(num_frogs, num_toads):
    state=['Frog']*num_frogs+['']+['Toad']*num_toads
    return state

def find_space(state):
    return state.index('')

def is_frog(state, index):
    if state[index]=='Frog':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_toad(state, index):
    if state[index]=='Toad':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def move(state, index):
    newState=list(state)
    newState[newState.index('')]=newState[index]
    newState[index]=''
    return newState

def print_state(state):
    print(*state,sep='|')

def is_win(state):
    if state==state[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def solvable(state):
    if is_win(state) == True:
        print(state)
        return True
    elif is_win(state) == False:
        return False
    else:
        N=find_space(state)
        if is_frog(state,N-1):
            newState=move(state,N-1)
            print(newState)
            return solvable(newState)
        
        elif is_frog(state,N-2):
            newState=move(state,N-2)
            print(newState)
            return solvable(newState)
        
        elif is_toad(state,N-1):
            newState=move(state,N-1)
            print(newState)
            return solvable(newState)
        
        elif is_toad(state,N-2):
            newState=move(state,N-2)
            print(newState)
            return solvable(newState)
        else:
            print('False')
     
def main():
    num_frogs=int(input('Enter the number of frogs: \n'))
    num_toads=int(input('Enter the number of toads: \n'))
    print()
    print('Here is the intial state:')
    state=make_state(num_frogs,num_toads)
    print_state(state)
    print()
    print('Here is the solution (in reverse):')
    print(solvable(state))
main()```

I have tried changing the solvable function() to be able to print the expected outcome but the actual outcome that I get is always False.
````

Answer (score 1):

you should always use `is` when comparing False,True or None

```
if is_win(state) is True:
    print(state)
    return True
elif is_win(state) is False:
    return False
```

to see this try

```
print( 0 == False ,  0 is False)
```

but thats not your problem ... is win returns either true or false ... so nothing beyond the first two if statements is reachable at all (eg nothing in the else is ever hit)